# Is there a way to move the focus to a modal when the modal is opened without the tabindex = -1 attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog, accessibility, tabindex

I know that the focus shifts to modal due to the `tabindex=-1` property when the modal opens.

Is there a way to move the focus to a modal when the modal is opened without the `tabindex=-1` attribute?

Comment: I tried to answer your other question, what are you actually trying to achieve as this question contradicts that question. Do you want to provide a code example and a step by step of what you are expecting to happen as I think you are not wording questions well enough for people to answer.

Comment: I'm looking for a variety of solutions for this problem.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60631666/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-the-default-behavior-of-the-a-tag-with-the-tabindex
I've simply added sample code to the question in the link. Thank you!!

Comment: right so I am clear are you wanting to focus your modal issue without needing a tabindex? If so I presume you have a close button on the modal (and if not you need one :-P) so set the focus on that and then I can point you to how to trap focus within a modal window. This is the best pattern for accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed there is, which is also the correct way using JavaScript focus the Close button of the modal. Here is one example to elaborate.

```
<div class='modal' aria-describedby='modalDescription'>
  <a href="#" class="close" title="close button">X</a>
  <div class='modal-content'>
    <p class='text' >
    This is a dialog window which 
    </p>
    <button type="submit" aria-label="Know More">Know More</button>
    <a href="#" class="redirect-close"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now using jquery or native javaScript on model open first focus the close button next tabbing will keep the focus on model focus-able elements in DOM until `.redirect-close` link is reached then it will move the focus back to the close button with class `.close`

Answer (score -1):

Indeed, there is:
You just need to focus on the first focusable element in the dialog via JS when the popup is open.